# Update SQL with a JOIN condition based on a case when

Tags: sas

I have a dataset (BASE)with the following strucuture: a column with a index for every records, a column with a classification type, the classification value and a column i'd like to populate.

```
NAME |CLASSIFICATION|VALUE|STANDARD VALUE
FIDO |ALFABET       |F    |
ALFA |STANDARD      |2    |
BETA |STANDARD      |5    |
ETA  |MIXED         |B65  |
THETA|MIXED         |A40  |
```

Not all records have the same classification, however I have an additional table (TRANSCODE) to convert the different classification methods into the standard one (which is classification):

```
ALFABET|STANDARD|MIXED
A      |1       |A1
B      |5       |A30
C      |3       |A40
D      |5       |A31
E      |8       |B65
F      |6       |C54
```

My goal is to populate the fourth column with the corresponding value i can find with the second table. (the records with the standard classification will have two columns with the same classification).
After that my data should be like the following:

```
NAME |CLASSIFICATION|VALUE|STANDARD VALUE
FIDO |ALFABET       |F    |6
ALFA |STANDARD      |2    |2
BETA |STANDARD      |5    |5
ETA  |MIXED         |B65  |8
THETA|MIXED         |A40  |3
```

In order to do so i'm trying to do a proc sql update with a join condition but it doesn't seem to work

```
    proc sql;
    update BASE
    left join TRASCODE
    on BASE.VALUE= (
        case 
            when BASE.CLASSIFCATION = 'ALFABET' then TRANSCODE.ALFABET 
            when BASE.CLASSIFICATION= 'STANDARD' then TRANSCODE.STANDARD
            when BASE.CLASSIFICATION= 'MIXED then TRANSCODE.MIXED
        end
    )
    set BASE.STANDARD_VALUE = TRANSCODE.STANDARD
;
quit;
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value selection for the standard value is a lookup query, so you can not join directly to transcode.

Try this UPDATE query that uses a different lookup selection for each classification:

```
data base;
infile cards missover;
input 
NAME $ CLASSIFICATION $ VALUE $ STANDARD_VALUE $; datalines;
FIDO  ALFABET       F    
ALFA  STANDARD      2    
BETA  STANDARD      5    
ETA   MIXED         B65  
THETA MIXED         A40  
run;
data transcode;
input 
ALFABET $ STANDARD $ MIXED $; datalines;
A      1       A1
B      5       A30
C      3       A40
D      5       A31
E      8       B65
F      6       C54
run;

proc sql;
  update base
  set standard_value = 
    case
      when classification = 'ALFABET'  then (select standard from transcode where alfabet=value)
      when classification = 'MIXED'    then (select standard from transcode where mixed=value)
      when classification = 'STANDARD' then value
      else 'NOTRANSCODE'
    end;

%let syslast = base;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and detailed answer, it worked! 
Thanks again